# Swift UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet for display some HTML content. But scrollView not appear.

```
let uiNavController : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyHtmlClass)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet
    presentViewController(uiNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is possible to show the scrollView ?

Answer (score 0):

You defined your `UINavigationController` as `uiNavController` then set `modalPresentationStyle` of `navController`. Replace this;

```
uiNavController.modalPresentationStyle = .PageSheet
```

Comment: I replace it but scrollBar doesn't appear

Comment: Are you try to present on iPhone?

Comment: I am trying to present in iPad